# Making Discord.py bot case-insensitive

Tags: discord, client, discord.py

Is it possible to use the `case_insensitive` attribute on the Discord client? I would like this so my bot can respond to any command even if the user called command contains uppercase or lowercase.

Answer (score 2):

The `case_insensitive` attribute does not defy between `bot` or `client`, even so, it's not hard to change it. They are both able to use this attribute. You can easily enable your bot to be case insensitive by defining it in your `client`

```
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "your prefix", case_insensitive=True)
```

It's also much easier to define your client on the same line instead of just doing `discord.Client()`

Answer (score 1):

See the attributes of a discord.ext.commands.Bot: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=sensitive#bot

See the attributes of a discord.Client:
https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=discord%20client#client

The attribute [`cse_insensitive`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=sensitive#discord.ext.commands.Bot.case_insensitive) is listed for the Bot but not for the Client. It does not exist in the Client. This means it is not possible.